# Using Ampscript to display an already set variable within an IF statement with another set variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I know the subject line might not make too much sense so hopefully my description will make sense. I have the below code in my Ampscript

```
IF @ModelCode == 'AC' THEN SET @ModelName = 'A1234' ENDIF
IF @ModelCode == 'CR' THEN SET @ModelName = 'C1234' ENDIF
IF @ModelCode == 'HR' THEN SET @ModelName = 'H5467' ENDIF
IF @ModelCode == 'OD' THEN SET @ModelName = 'O9876' ENDIF
IF @ModelCode == 'CI' THEN SET @ModelName = 'C5234' ENDIF

IF @Model == 'HR' THEN SET @Subject = 'All-new HR'
ELSEIF @Model == 'CI' THEN SET @Subject = 'All-new CI'
ELSE SET @Subject = 'Original %%=v(@Modelname)=%%'
ENDIF]%%
```

The first part of the @subject IF statement is working correctly but the (@Modelname) that is contained within the ELSE SET for @Subject is not pulling in the model name and instead is just showing the subject of 'Original %%=v(@Modelname)=%%'

eg. If the @modelcode selected in my data is 'AC' the @subject should be showing 'Original A1234'

Is there a workaround to ensure the set value for @modelname is pulled in?

Thank you advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `IF @Model == 'HR' THEN` be `IF @ModelCode == 'HR'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a string as a combination of text and ampscript variable, you should use the [concat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/Concat.html) function:

```
ELSE SET @Subject = Concat('Original ',@Modelname)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked flawlessly. Cheers